# Cant update relations on Update action in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When updating a resource called JobsI want to copy some of the values from this update to some resources connected to this resource

Jobs has many Hours each hour has a period with 2 set of times. So if i  update the job with these times i want them copied down to the periods

I tried this code in different variants but the periods entities dont get updated.

```
  def update
@job = Job.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @job.update_attributes(params[:job])

    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    @job.hours.each do |hour|
      logger.debug params[:job][:start1]
      logger.debug params[:job][:end1]
      hour.periods.first.start_time = params[:job][:start1]
      hour.periods.first.end_time = params[:job][:end1]
      hour.periods.last.start_time = params[:job][:start2]
      hour.periods.last.end_time = params[:job][:end2]
    end

    @job.save

    format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you closer to telling which code is failing, but you could have all sorts of things going wrong in there. If this doesn't work, uncomment that `binding.pry` and make sure the hour attributes have updated Also, looks like you're getting `@job` twice? Give this a shot:

```
def update
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @job && @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
      logger.debug "Job updated attributes"
      @job.hours.each do |hour|
        hour.periods.first.update_attributes(start_time: params[:job][:start1])
        hour.periods.first.update_attributes(end_time: params[:job][:end1])
        hour.periods.last.update_attributes(start_time: params[:job][:start2])
        hour.periods.last.update_attributes(end_time: params[:job][:end2])
        # binding.pry
      end

      @job.save!

      format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

You could speed up the updates a little bit by calling `update_column` on the period records. i.e. `hour.periods.first.update_column(:start_time, params[:job][:start_time])`, but you would lose any validation or callbacks on your period model by doing so.

Comment: Great, that worked. The big difference was ! at save? hmm Can you explain? I didnt uncomment the binding.pry. Was trying to load it twice, just to play around..

Comment: The bang ! method will raise an exception if it doesn't complete. In this case I think it would prevent the call to `format`. It's useful for debugging so you can tell exactly where your code fails. I think the calls to `update_attributes` were what you were missing. Glad it works either way.

Comment: Got back to this code and it made me wonder if it could be done in a transaction? So it would either save the job and update the others or fail both of them.